# How to adjust GUI.Label text so that each letter have the same space no matter the size?

Tags: unity-editor

I'm trying to display simple text in `UnityEditor` window

So I did the following:

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(position.width - (position.width / 2), 60, 200, 20), "..........................", label);
GUI.Label(new Rect(position.width - (position.width / 2), 80, 200, 20), "..oo..oo..oo..oo..oo..oo..", label);
```

so it should show in the editor window with the same spacing between letters to align.

Like bellow:

```
".........................."
"..oo..oo..oo..oo..oo..oo.."
```

As you can see above they have the same spacing and the same occupied width but in the editor window it shows the following:

[image]

As you can see above the letter spacing is different (letter `o` takes more space than letter `.`)

How can I solve this problem?